# How to duplicate row from MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am rewriting all of my code using PDO. I'm stuck rewriting a DuplicateMySQLRecord function in PDO.

function DuplicateMySQLRecord ($table, $id_field, $id)

I just can't wrap my mind around this - have taken many stabs at it, and it all is a miserable failure.

Can someone help a brother out?

Comment: Please add more detail to the question.. What does the function do?

Comment: The function copies a row from a table into the same table given the variables: $table, $id_field, $id.

Comment: Philip Whitehouse below gets exactly what I;m doing, only problem is that his code is vulnerable and that is what I need to replace with PDO.

Comment: What's the point in duplicating rows? How this function is going to be used and what for?

Comment: Sometimes we need to create new records that are identical to existing records with only one field changed. It is a booking system. Sometimes a guest will need to create multiple bookings with the exact same data aside from the unit they are renting. It is much too infrequent to build database structure around, but often enough to be a PITA to put all that data in by hand again.

Comment: If it's not for any row an arbitrary table in the database it's a much easier problem. Just do a select and then an insert with all the other fields.

Comment: there's your solution op. next time, you should probably consider reading the help docs.

Answer (score 0):

why should you make a function for this?

`INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column="data"`

keep in mind, if you don't have a unique delimiter (id, etc), this WILL cause BIG problems.

take this for example:

Lets say I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-------------+-------+----------+
| something   | other | there_is |
+-------------+-------+----------+
| huh         | what  | no id    |
+-------------+-------+----------+
```

And I execute

`INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE there_is="no id"`

Now we have

```
+-------------+-------+----------+
| something   | other | there_is |
+-------------+-------+----------+
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
+-------------+-------+----------+
```

What if I want to execute it again? That worked right? Well, this time we'll get:

```
+-------------+-------+----------+
| something   | other | there_is |
+-------------+-------+----------+
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
+-------------+-------+----------+
```

And then

```
+-------------+-------+----------+
| something   | other | there_is |
+-------------+-------+----------+
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
| huh         | what  | no id    |
+-------------+-------+----------+
```

etc.. So set an unique identifier.

Comment: It did not work. I got error "Duplicate entry 'xxx' for key 'PRIMARY'" for my case. The column is id.

Answer (score -1):

**Unsafe code - this is highly vulnerable to SQL injection. Proper usage of prepared statements is strongly advised.**

Based on the function name:

```
function DuplicateMySQLRecord ($table, $id_field, $id) {
   $result = $dbconn->query("SELECT * FROM ".$table." 
                                WHERE ".$id_field." = '".$id."' LIMIT 1");
   $row = $result[0];
   $SQL = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (";
   $first = true;
   foreach($row as $key=>$val) {
      if($key != $id_field) {
         if(!$first) {
           $SQL.=',';
           $SQL .=$key;
        }
      }
   }
   foreach($row as $key=>$val) {
      if($key != $id_field) {
         if(!$first) {
           $SQL.=',';
           $SQL .="'".$val."'";
         }
      }
   }
   $dbconn->exec($SQL);
 }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is vulnerable code is exactly what I'm trying to *replace* with PDO code, so it is not what I asked for.

Comment: I did answer your question as asked, which was an implementation in PDO - that uses PDO. Given that you showed no effort or attempt yourself - even pseudo code, I saw little point in just doing it all for you.